# Remote users on domain share

Tags: windows

I am trying to share a domain share so only a specific machine with a specific user can connect.

I have tried all the normal ways of actually adding the computer to the domain and then using its unc to map a user but to no avail.

Is this possible? How do you do this?

Comment: is this user going to be interactively logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [domain and server isolation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545651.aspx)